# How to determine the clicked item in a grid view

Tags: c++, xaml, uwp, winrt-xaml, c++-winrt

Given a `GridView` such as

```xml
<GridView IsItemClickEnabled="True"  ItemClick="favorite_clicked" ItemsSource="{x:Bind MainViewModel.FavoriteBinders}" Grid.Column="1">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate   x:DataType="local:FavoriteBinder">
            <StackPanel AccessKey="{x:Bind CedictId, Mode=OneWay}"  Width="200" Margin="20">
            <TextBlock   Text="{x:Bind Simplified, Mode=OneWay}" FontWeight="Bold" 
              />
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Pinyin, Mode=OneWay}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" 
                />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</GridView.ItemTemplate>
<GridView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <ItemsWrapGrid MaximumRowsOrColumns="7"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</GridView.ItemsPanel>
```

Which is populated with a type`FavoriteBinder` that has a int32_t field called id.

And a click function that looks like:

```cpp
void FavoritesPage::favorite_clicked(
    Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& sender, 
    Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs const& args) 
{
}
```

How can I get the id of the item clicked in the favorite_clicked function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In favorite_clicked event, you can get the FavoriteBinder class you click by **e.ClickedItem()** method, and use **.as** method to convert the object to FavoriteBinder type.

```
void FavoritesPage::favorite_clicked(IInspectable const& sender, winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::ItemClickEventArgs const& e)
{
    WinrtText::FavoriteBinder clickVM = e.ClickedItem().as< WinrtText::FavoriteBinder >();
    int32_t clickId = clickVM.CedictId();
}
```